# Provisioning Sites, Lists, Libraries etc within SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, office365

Previously when provisioning list, libraries, site columns, content types, list definitions etc in SharePoint I typically used SharePoint features, deployed via a WSP - or used PowerShell scripts.  This meant I had a package that could be deployed to DEV / TEST / PROD.

I'm working with SharePoint within Office 365 and unsure on the best way to provision lists / libraries / features within SharePoint.

Options:

**No Code Sandboxed Solutions**
Trying to avoid using these as the information from Microsoft on whether they are deprecated is flaky - however sandboxed solutions would allow me to deploy features with list definitions etc.  I know sandboxed solutions with c# are definitely deprecated, but the info around no code solutions is poor.

**Apps**
I know apps can provision at both the app and host web level, but creating lists, libraries etc using the CSOM seems like a lot of effort and a step backwards.

**PowerShell**
The SP Online PowerShell is nowhere near as powerful as on-prem SP. I can provision site collections through this, but not lists or libraries...

I'm keen to know how other developers are deploying to Office 365, specifically around provisioning sites with specific list definitions, libraries, content types and so on...

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Microsoft did clarify the position on No Code Sandbox solutions - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sharepointdev/archive/2014/01/14/deprecation-of-custom-code-in-sandboxed-solutions.aspx

Also if you are looking at using Powershell to deploy then you might want to go down the route of using CSOM from within PowerShell - SharePoint Client Browser for SharePoint 2013 is good for setting up a session also very good for viewing the content of a 365 tenant - http://spcb.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

I have been using code based provision for almost two years without any issues at all.
Server side model works just fine, CSOM has some limitation but stil cool one and JSOM could deliver the same feature set as both CSOM and SSOM, sorta 95% :)

PowerShell is not the best option as it hard to integrate into CI, put some unit testing and regressions.

As you mentioned, this is "step back", but if only you don't have any framework or foundation for that. My libraries are internal one, but there is SPGenesis at codeplex and SPMeta2.
As community don't really care, need or with such libraries for provisioning (yep, let's face it), there are much such libraries at all, but there are lots of "MVP" samples sorta "hello world" level.

Finally, what I would suggest is to invest your time and effort in code based provision.
This is a future, that's it ;)

**UPD**

Struggling with SharePoint's API inconsistency, bugs, "by-design" behaviour, unaffordable amount of time to write, support and upgrade WSP packages and XML, a team of passionate SharePoint professionals decided to come up with robust, testable and repeatable way to deploy such artifacts like fields, content types, libraries, pages and many more.

Enjoy and let us know how it goes.

- [SPMeta2 at GitHub](https://github.com/SubPointSolutions/spmeta2)
- [SPMeta2 at Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages?q=spmeta2)
- [SPMeta2 Documentation Wiki](https://github.com/SubPointSolutions/spmeta2/wiki)
- [SPMeta2 Bugtracker](https://github.com/SubPointSolutions/spmeta2/issues?milestone=3&state=open)